# Getting back to academics / independent research

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, computer-science

As a full time professional without prior publications, I am seriously considering a move to academics as a PhD student. My field of interest is mostly Data Analytics and I am keen to explore the possibilities where I can associate Data Analytics with AI and Deep Learning.

Unfortunately, I have no degrees or certificates to show my credentials here but I have prepared myself in the tools I may need to tackle a research question in such a discipline.(Yes, I agree that it isn't enough)

I want to know if there is any possibility of collaborating with academic professionals and publish independent papers?

My academic qualifications:

Bachelors in Computer Science and Engineering 
MBA in International Management

Comment: Do you have a university degree (in any field)? Otherwise it will be very hard to get a job at an academic institution.

Comment: Academics with many publications cannot get a stable job, how would you expect to get a position with one or two publications?

Comment: Your follow up question is off-topic because it is "shopping" question, which is off topic. Please edit your question to remove it.

Comment: By position, I intended to mean admission to a program and not an employment. My apologies for the confusion. I have a Bachelors in Computer Science and Engineering and I also have an MBA.

Comment: Please update the question on your degrees, this is important. You might want to start a PhD, maybe even as a side-track to your current job. However, a PhD guarantees nothing in terms of employment safety.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to get into a PhD program. I am not really focusing on employment guarantees after one right now.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which you can be involved in research, coming out of industry.

It is possible to enroll in a PhD program.  There are normally no age requirements, and it is not unheard of for people to start a PhD later in their career.  Depending on where you are, this may require a Master degree first.  I suspect many PIs are happy to enroll someone with substantial industry experience.

It is also possible to find employment at a company that cooperates with university research.  It's quite common for small and medium enterprises to cooperate with universities in projects (for some funding agencies such as the European Commission, this is in fact a requirement), so with the right skills, expertise, and contacts, that should be possible.  For example, within the EU, [Horizon 2020](https://ec.europa.eu/programmes/horizon2020) projects always must involve such enterprises.

Gaining full employment (not counting RA/TA/PhD studies) at a university without already having a PhD degree and recent publications is not feasible.

Comment: No, I do not intend to do this as part of my job. I want to move to academic employment. But before I apply anywhere, I want to have one or two academic publications. If that takes a year or more, I'm okay with it.

I will check the Horizon 2020 projects though. Thanks!

Comment: "*I want to move to academic employment*" I don't understand how this could be possible with no degrees. At least in the U.S., even teaching at a community college requires at least a Masters degree.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Maybe with an [honorary degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorary_degree)?

Comment: Perhaps, but I wouldn't hold my breath for this avenue. Also, many of the degree restrictions I've seen say "earned".

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. By 'academic employment' I meant admission to a PhD program with a RA/TA. In terms of degrees, I hold a Bachelors in Computer Sc and an MBA

Comment: @PrithwishSarkar Wait, you want to enter a PhD program as a student? That's really important info that you should include in your question. It might be obvious to you that that's what you mean by "a move to academics" but that's not clear to the rest of us.